# Как добавить запись в базу данных к авторизированному пользователю

Tags: sql, python-3.x, база-данных, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть база данных с пользователями. Положим непосредственно сейчас некто авторизировался, выбрал несколько блюд и нажал на кнопку "добавить в избранное". Почему-то сейчас они записываются как новая запись в таблице, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы запись была добавлена ту же строчку, что и пользователь, в отведенную ему графу fav. Чтобы никого не путать, все остальные мои пробные пользователи были удалены. [Ссылка на GitHub](https://github.com/artisakov/vigilant-journey)

```
@app.route('/favourites', methods=['POST','GET'])
def favour():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list1 = request.form.getlist('row')
        str1 = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in list1])
        new_fav = User(fav = str1)
        db.session.add(new_fav)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('index.html', name=current_user.username)
```

[image: Список продуктов]
[image: База данных]

Коллективным разумом решение проблемы было найдено вот так :

```
@app.route('/favourites', methods=['POST','GET'])
def favour():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list1 = request.form.getlist('row')
        str1 = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in list1])
        con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\FFlaskApplication\\app\\database.db')  
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute('UPDATE user SET fav = ? WHERE username = ?',(str1,current_user.username))
        con.close()
        return render_template('index.html', name=current_user.username)
```

Comment: Так потому что вы создаете запись только с одним заполненным полем, а вам надо апдейтить существующую запись

Comment: вооот, это я и спрашиваю, как ее апдейтить

Comment: Пишите запрос и используйте через execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну обновляйте через курсор обычным выполнением запроса.

1. `update_query = "Update _tableName set _tableValue = ? where [user id] = ?"` - создаете шаблон запроса, `?` - места, куда вы будете передавать значения в дальнейшем
2. `cursor.execute(update_query, (param1, param2))` - выполняете апдейт через курсор, инициализированный на вашем соединении.

Пример:

```
import sqlite3    
try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\fst\\database.db')
except Error as e:
    print(e)    
cursor = con.cursor()
query = '''UPDATE user SET fav = NULL WHERE id = 1'''
cursor.execute(query)
query = '''SELECT * FROM user'''
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
query = '''UPDATE user SET fav = '1,2,3' WHERE id = 1'''
cursor.execute(query)
query = '''SELECT * FROM user'''
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Ответ:

```
(1, 'artemtvi', 'art.isackov@gmail.com', 'ShurfLL1', None)
(2, 'artemtvi1', 'art.isackow@gmail.com', 'ShurfLL1', None)
(1, 'artemtvi', 'art.isackov@gmail.com', 'ShurfLL1', '1,2,3')
(2, 'artemtvi1', 'art.isackow@gmail.com', 'ShurfLL1', None)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104781/discussion-on-answer-by-vladimir-afanasyev--------).

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica почему-то не было в этот раз кнопки переноса в чат:(